# Why is't my form working in php/html?

Tags: php, html

im trying to pass a variable with a submit button and it doesn't work.

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION=<?php echo "\"add_event.php?email=".$email."\""?>>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="add event">
</FORM>
```

$email is fine in the page that's calling it.

```
http://localhost/aproject/add_event.php?
```

that is the url that's passed.

not

```
http://localhost/aproject/add_event.php?email=myemail@email.com
```

as I want.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

edit:

the generated html is

```
<form method="LINK" action="add_event.php?email=closeded@gmail.com">
<input type="submit" value="add event">
</form>
```

Comment: `METHOD="LINK"` ? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: check the generated HTML content.

Comment: somewhere, I don't remember where. I am inept at php and html this is for a databases class.  It works though when I don't try to pass variables.

Comment: this is the generated html

Comment: @d0m1n1c — No, that is the PHP. The generated HTML is what you get when you execute the PHP.

Comment: I see recall from 90's with that all caps HTML

Comment: sorry, I added the generated html

Comment: Why do you even need to submit a blank form? You can just generate a link with query string.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha it seems to be written two decades ago, if I were you, I would not dare to object :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such form method as `LINK`, so your form is using `GET` (the default).

When you submit a GET form, you will destroy any existing query string on the form action and replace it with one generated from the form data.

Use a hidden input to store your data instead.

```
<form action="add_event.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
  <input type="submit" VALUE="add event">
</form>
```

Comment: +1 for `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath — What about that is unclear?